# Javascript call the function, and pass the promt value to the function

Tags: javascript, function, math, call, command-prompt

I need to prompt the user for a radius and then calculate the circumference of a circle using a function. I can't get my function to run. Here is my code:

```js
function CircleCircumference(radius) {
    var circ = 2 * radius * MATH.PI;
    document.write("The Circumference of a circle with the radius " +
        radius + " is " + circ + ".");
} 

var radius = parseInt(prompt("Enter the radius of a circle:"));
```

Comment: `MATH` is not defined.. should be `Math.PI`

Comment: you are almost done. Just change "MATH" to "Math". And add one more line, "CircleCircumference(radius);"

Comment: You never call your method

Answer (score 0):

it should be [Math.PI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pi.asp). Try something like this, demo in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/dctpg58y/)

JS

```
$('#btn').click(CircleCircumference);
function CircleCircumference () {
    var radius = parseInt(prompt("Enter the radius of a circle:"));
    //alert(radius);
    var circ = 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    //alert(circ);
    alert("The Circumference of a circle with the radius " +radius+ " is " +circ+ ".");
}
```

HTML

```
<input type='button' id='btn' value='click me'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
function CircleCircumference(radius) {
    var circ = 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    document.write("The Circumference of a circle with the radius " +radius+ " is " +circ+ ".");
} 
var radius = CircleCircumference(parseInt(prompt("Enter the radius of a circle:")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there are two main errors with your code:

1. There's no such native object as `MATH`. You want the `Math` object. JavaScript is case-sensitive.
2. You forgot to call `CircleCircumference(radius)` after you got the `radius` from the user.

However, there's a lot that you could do to make your code better:

1. I would move the `document.write` statement out of the `CircleCircumference` function as it doesn't make any sense for it to be there.
2. Instead of `document.write` I would use either `alert` or `console.log`.
3. I would rename `CircleCircumference` to `circumference`. Capital letters, by convention, should only be used for constructor functions.
4. I would explicitly write `parseInt(x, 10)` where `x` is your `prompt` expression and `10` is base 10 (decimal system). This tells `parseInt` to expect a decimal number only.

This is how my code would look:

```js
var radius = parseInt(prompt("Enter the radius of a circle:"), 10);

alert("The circumference of a circle with radius " +
    radius + " is " + circumference(radius));

function circumference(radius) {
    return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the word "MATH" to "Math" and run your code again as MATH will give you an error "MATH is not defined". don't forget to call your function name after you declared your function. you might change your code to...

```
function CircleCircumference(radius) {
    var circ = 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    document.write("The Circumference of a circle with the radius " +radius+ " is " +circ+ ".");
} 
CircleCircumference(parseInt(prompt("Enter the radius of a circle:")));
```